# Is it ok, then additional tags of Angular break html-layout in dev mode?

Tags: angular

I insert two components inside template of another one.

```
// my.component.html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <app-products-menu [dropped]="false"></app-products-menu>
    <app-top-menu></app-top-menu>
  </div>
</div>
```

And after ng serve -o I look at page source html code:

[image]

Of course bootstrap cols within row don't work. How can I test my html? Maybe I have posibillity to turn off this feature or smth else?

Comment: Put the `<div class="col">` in my.component instead of app-products-menu / app-top-menu. Requiring these components to be placed in a certain kind of layout (in this case a div.row) defeats the purpose of making them components (reusability).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of options. In both cases, you'll need to remove the `<div class="col"></div>` from your component templates.

If you want to avoid the presence of the custom tag for each component, you can change your selector for each to an attribute, e.g.: `selector: '[appProductsMenu]'` and bind that to the columns:

```html
<div appProductsMenu class="col"></div>
```

Another option is to remove the columns from the components and move the class to your component tags:

```html
<app-products-menu class="col"></app-products-menu>
```

This is often the case when you're working with a CSS framework that expects a certain hierarchy.

Comment: Thank you, Brandon. That's that I needed. But why is there nothing about this use case  in angular documentation? I mean using selector: '[appProductsMenu]'. How could I know it without your advice?

Comment: You're welcome. You can learn a lot by following the trail of documentation provided  by VS Code's IntelliSense. If you put your cursor over the selector portion of the component decorator, you'll see all of the possibilities.